# Italicize the caption in ggplotly figure

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggplotly

I am not sure why the caption is not changing, I might be using the wrong functions. Here is an example:

My dataframe `moment.curve`:

```
moment.curv <- structure(list(row = 1:5, Curvature = c(
  0, 0.001805, 0.004512,
  0.008121, 0.0126
), Moment = c(
  0, 192.0442, 242.8942, 256.6455,
  258.1099
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

I use the following code to create the plot:

```
plot.moment.curv <- ggplot(moment.curv) +
 aes(x = Curvature, y = Moment) +
 geom_line(size = 1L, colour = "#0c4c8a") +
 labs(x = "bla", y = "bla") + theme_classic()
```

I use the following to create a ggplotly interactive plot, keep in mind I want to keep this format that I make the original plot in ggplot and then convert it to an interactive plot with ggplotly. The actual figures I am creating are much more complicated and this makes the process easier.

```
ggplotly(
  p = ggplot2::last_plot(),
  width = NULL,
  height = NULL,
  tooltip = "all",
  dynamicTicks = FALSE,
  layerData = 1,
  originalData = TRUE,
) %>% 
 layout(margin = list(b=130,t=100), annotations = 
 list(x = 1, y = -0.4, text = "THE CAPTION", 
      showarrow = F, xref='paper', yref='paper', 
      xanchor='right', yanchor='auto', xshift=0, yshift=0,
      font=list(size=15,fontfacet="italic"))
 )
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the font face you have to use HTML tags, i.e. to italicize your caption use `text = "<i>THE CAPTION</i>"`.

[image]