# Trying to add color coding to the title of ggplotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, ggplotly, ggtext

I am trying to produce a graph where the title has color coded text to remove the need for a legend. I have no problem doing this in `ggplot2` using the `ggtext` package and `ggtext::element_markdown()`.
However, when I try to then layer on top `ggplotly`, the color disappears.

I am wondering if there is any way to combine the color functionality with `ggplotly`?

Here is a sample reproducible example using the `mtcars` dataset.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)
library(ggtext)

mtcolors<-c("springgreen4", "darkorange3", "purple")
names(mtcolors)<-c("4 cyl", "6 cyl", "8 cyl")

mt_title_text <- glue::glue(
  'MPG vs HP -',  
  '<span style = "color:{mtcolors["4 cyl"]}">**4 cyl**</span>', 
  'vs.',
  '<span style = "color:{mtcolors["6 cyl"]}">**6 cyl**</span>',
  'vs.',
  '<span style = "color:{mtcolors["8 cyl"]}">**8 cyl**</span>',
  .sep = ' '
)

mtcars |>
  mutate(
    cyl = as.factor(cyl)
  ) |>
  ggplot(aes(x=mpg, y=hp, color=cyl)) +
  geom_point(size=3) +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("springgreen4", "darkorange3", "purple")) +
  labs(
    title = mt_title_text
  ) +
  theme(
    plot.title = ggtext::element_markdown(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    legend.position = 'none'
  )
```

This produces the following graph:

[image]

However, when I add ggplotly to add the interactive functionality, the markdown text in the title returns to just normal text:

```
mtcarsexp<-
  mtcars |>
  mutate(
    cyl = as.factor(cyl)
  ) |>
  ggplot(aes(x=mpg, y=hp, color=cyl)) +
  geom_point(size=3) +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("springgreen4", "darkorange3", "purple")) +
  labs(
    title = mt_title_text
  ) +
  theme(
    plot.title = ggtext::element_markdown(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    legend.position = 'none'
  ) 

ggplotly(mtcarsexp)
```

[image]

It seems that perhaps I could use the concept in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63144642/italicize-the-caption-in-ggplotly-figure) and, rather than use the title in the `labs`, just create text, and position it in the place of the title, but I would much prefer to use the native `labs` functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use html tags with `ggplotly`. Also, colors need to be either standard colors or the HEX codes.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)

mtcolors<-c("#00FF7F", "darkorange", "purple")
names(mtcolors)<-c("4 cyl", "6 cyl", "8 cyl")

mt_title_text <- glue::glue(
  'MPG vs HP -',  
  '<b style= "color:{mtcolors["4 cyl"]}">4 cyl</b>', 
  'vs.',
  '<b style= "color:{mtcolors["6 cyl"]}">6 cyl</b>',
  'vs.',
  '<b style= "color:{mtcolors["8 cyl"]}">8 cyl</b>',
  .sep = ' ')

mtcars %>% 
  mutate(
    cyl = as.factor(cyl)
  ) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=mpg, y=hp, color=cyl)) +
  geom_point(size=3) +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("springgreen4", "darkorange3", "purple")) +
  labs(
    title = mt_title_text
  ) +
  theme(
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    legend.position = 'none'
  ) -> p

ggplotly(p)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-03-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>